# How to use generics in parameter properly

Tags: java, generics

I have this right now:

```
  public <T> void run(T x){

    if(x instanceof HashMap){
      ((HashMap<String,String>)x).put("foo","bar");
    }

  }
```

but I see this warning:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I have three questions:

1. Does anyone know what that warning is about?
2. Am I using the instanceof operator right? Is there a better/more accurate check to use?
3. Is there some way of using generics so that the method "knows" what the type is so I don't have to cast the type?

Comment: What is the goal of your method, what is the expectation of variable types that you could pass in? As written `T` is an Object and nothing further can be determined. The unchecked cast is due to casting an object of unknown type to an map of string to strings. You can add @SuppressWarning("unchecked") to hide the warning, and in this case you could at least cast it to a HashMap, but you still don't know for sure what generic types are contained in the map, what if you passed a HashMap String, Integer?

Comment: well it's a known type inside of the if block right?

Comment: You know it's a HashMap, but you don't know it's a HashMap<String, String>

Answer (score 1):

This `T` can be of any type that extends `Object` and your code is not type safe. If anything otherthan `HashMap<String, String>` is passed in you may get a `ClassCastException`. But the use of `instance of` operator will prevent that from happening. But still anyone can send any object to your method. So the unchecked warning merely states that.

Use of instance of seems bit awkward to me here. Rather if you want to add an entry to existing map, you can change the declaration of your generic method like so,

```
public <S, T extends Map<S, S>> void addEntryToMap(T x, S key, S value) {
    x.put(key, value);
}
```

This code is type-safe, more cleaner and elegant than instance of check approach above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to achieve in your method

```
public <T> void run(T x){ // Gets an unbounded T which means it can accept anything under Object.

    if(x instanceof HashMap){
      ((HashMap<String,String>)x).put("foo","bar"); // How are you so sure it is an HashMap<String,String>? It can be any HashMap,or even Object!! That is exactly why your compiler is telling it is doing an unchecked cast.
    }
  }
```

That answers your first point.

Second point, we need more clarity on this to explain.

Third point, There is something called type-erasure in Java where the generic method wont be able to know the type of object at runtime. You can pass in the class for casting or need to use bounded wild-cards for compile-time check.